# Column not found at liquibase migration for H2 in-memory database

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2, liquibase

I had to replace my PostgreSQL database with an H2 in-memory database and my migration started to fail. The create table script runs but the insert fails.

```
ChangeSet classpath:database/changelog/create-default-user.xml::createUserTable::ethero ran successfully in 7ms
Change Set classpath:database/changelog/create-default-user.xml::insertDefaultUser::ethero failed.  Error: Column "username" not found; SQL statement:
```

Error Stacktrace

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set classpath:database/changelog/create-default-user.xml::insertDefaultUser::ethero:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Column "username" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO usr ("username", "password") VALUES ('admin', 'password') [42122-200] [Failed SQL: (42122) INSERT INTO usr ("username", "password") VALUES ('admin', 'password')]
```

Create table script

```
create table user_authorities (username varchar(255) not null , authorities varchar(255));
create table usr (username varchar(255) not null , password varchar(255), image_url varchar(255))
```

Insert user script

```
INSERT INTO usr ("username", "password") VALUES ('admin', 'password');
INSERT INTO user_authorities ("username", "authorities") VALUES ('admin', 'ADMIN');
INSERT INTO user_authorities ("username", "authorities") VALUES ('admin', 'USER');
```

Spring boot configuration

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:pc;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;
    username: sa
    password: sa
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
  jpa:
    generate-ddl: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true

  liquibase:
    change-log: classpath:database/changelog-master.xml
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:pc;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
```

Spring boot version: 2.4.3

Comment: The `INSERT` statements are using quoted column names, in which case each column name must match the case (upper/lower) of the column as defined in the table. You did _not_ use quoted column names in the `create table` statements, so I _guess_ that `username` was created as an uppercase column identifier. You can test my guess by trying `INSERT INTO usr ("USERNAME", "PASSWORD") VALUES ('admin', 'password');` or `INSERT INTO usr (username, password) VALUES ('admin', 'password');`.

Comment: Possibly related: [Make H2 treat quoted name and unquoted name as the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10789994/make-h2-treat-quoted-name-and-unquoted-name-as-the-same).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL and few other DBMS are different from others: they convert unquoted identifiers to lower case. H2 and many others convert unquoted identifiers to upper case and such behavior is actually a standard one.

If you want to use both DBMS for a some reason, you can add `;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE` to JDBC url of H2, with this parameter H2 will treat case of identifiers in the same way as PostgreSQL does.

But if you want to use only the H2, it would be better not to use such settings and adjust your SQL to use upper case letters in quoted identifiers.

Anyway, mixing quoted and unquoted identifiers is a bad practice. Usually it's better  to always quote or never quote them. Note that there are various reserved words and these words cannot be used as unquoted identifiers.